How do we create DLL in python?
I had made a tool using image grabbing in python but we do not need to create .exe for that instead we need to create DLL in one file
I am tired trying into making DLL but it seems  to be embedded with c++ code. Executable file needs to be renewed

Does this answer your question? How to compile a Python package to a dll
